# If Statement Inside a Function Not working

Tags: php, function, if-statement

Similar questions have been posted but I have not been able to find an answer.

This IF statement works correctly by it's self.

```
$subject_id_top = "case studies";
if($subject_id_top == "case studies") {echo "active";}
```

But when I inserted this IF statement inside a function it does not work.

```
<style>

.active {
color:#F00;
}
</style>


<?php 
$subject_id_top = "case studies";

function menu_active() {
 if($subject_id_top == "case studies") {echo "active";} 
}


<a class="<?php menu_active(); ?>" href="#">Case Studies</a>
?>
```

This seems to be a very basic issue but for the life of me I havent been able to figure it out. The community help will be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @fireeyedboy got the jump on me -- he's right. As a matter of note, your `<a>` element will not work in a page the way it is written now, inside the closing php tag (`?>`). You either need to put it outside that tag or use `echo` to print it. You've probably just written it this way for the purposes of your example here, but I bring it up just in case this is the way it also is on your site!

Comment: actually in my file it is outside ?>. I wrote it like this here by accident. will correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$subject_id_top` inside the function refers to `$subject_id_top` outside the scope of the function ([the global scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global)), you have to 'import' it, so to speak, with the statement:

```
global $subject_id_top;
```

You're function should then become:

```
function menu_active() {
    global $subject_id_top;
    if($subject_id_top == "case studies") {echo "active";} 
}
```

However, relying on information from outside scopes, in this way, is usually not preferable. You could refactor your function to accept an argument to circumvent this behavior, like so, for instance:

```
function menu_active( $subject_id_top ) {
    if($subject_id_top == "case studies") {echo "active";} 
}
```

And then call that function with `$subject_id_top`, from the global scope, as its argument:

```
<?php menu_active( $subject_id_top ); ?>
```

Comment: alternatively you could pass subject id to the function: menu_active($subject_id_top) - some argue against the use of globals like this, though it is a very common thing to do

Comment: @fireeyedboy As you can tell I am new to PHP and did not know that the value outside a function had to be "imported". Thanks for explaining this. Why would this be bad practice? Would it fail in a large environment?

Comment: I did some reading on global variables being used in a function and see the consequences that can arise. Thanks again.